# Can't save product in Magento 2.1 because attribute swatch_image can not be loaded

Tags: products, magento-2.1, debugging

Since upgrading to Magento 2.1, I can not save the products. Any hints? Did anybody see this issue already? I am facing following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /home/self/example/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 1611
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /home/self/example/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 1611
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0049  387808  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.1555  2811168 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run( ??? ) .../index.php:37
3   0.1563  2822848 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch( )   .../Bootstrap.php:258
4   0.2319  5415168 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch( ??? )  .../Http.php:135
5   0.2326  5402440 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins( ???, ???, ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:26
6   0.2448  5739976 Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch( ???, ???, ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:142
7   0.2450  5739928 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}( ??? )  .../DbStatusValidator.php:69
8   0.2450  5740304 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext( ???, ???, ???, ???, ??? )   .../Interceptor.php:138
9   0.2450  5740344 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent( ???, ??? )    .../Chain.php:70
10  0.2450  5740344 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch( ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:74
11  0.4053  10545560    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch( ??? )  .../FrontController.php:55
12  0.4066  10630936    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins( ???, ???, ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:39
13  0.5096  11648688    Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch( ???, ???, ??? )    .../Interceptor.php:142
14  0.5096  11648688    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}( ??? )  .../MassactionKey.php:33
15  0.5096  11649064    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext( ???, ???, ???, ???, ??? )   .../Interceptor.php:138
16  0.5140  11713816    Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch( ???, ???, ??? )   .../Chain.php:67
17  0.5282  11822624    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}( ??? )   .../Authentication.php:143
18  0.5282  11823000    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext( ???, ???, ???, ???, ??? )   .../Chain.php:63
19  0.5282  11823040    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent( ???, ??? )    .../Chain.php:70
20  0.5282  11823040    Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch( ??? ) .../Interceptor.php:74
21  0.5357  12090616    Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch( ??? )    .../AbstractAction.php:226
22  0.5408  12129880    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save\Interceptor->execute( )   .../Action.php:102
23  0.5409  12129880    Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save->execute( )   .../Interceptor.php:24
24  0.8590  22993064    Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->save( )  .../Save.php:110
25  0.8590  22993064    Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save( )  .../Interceptor.php:2351
26  0.8590  22993064    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->save( ??? )    .../AbstractModel.php:631
27  0.8590  22993440    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins( ???, ???, ??? )    .../Interceptor.php:273
28  0.8592  22996184    Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave( ???, ???, ??? )   .../Interceptor.php:142
29  0.8592  22996184    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}( ??? )    .../FlushCacheByTags.php:60
30  0.8592  22996560    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext( ???, ???, ???, ???, ??? )   .../Interceptor.php:138
31  0.8597  23074504    Magento\CatalogRule\Plugin\Indexer\Product\Save\ApplyRules->aroundSave( ???, ???, ??? ) .../Chain.php:67
32  0.8597  23074504    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}( ??? )   .../ApplyRules.php:40
33  0.8597  23074880    Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext( ???, ???, ???, ???, ??? )   .../Chain.php:63
34  0.8598  23074952    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent( ???, ??? )  .../Chain.php:70
35  0.8598  23074952    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->save( ??? )    .../Interceptor.php:74
36  0.8598  23074952    Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save( ???, ??? ) .../Product.php:695
37  0.8635  23211944    Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute( ???, ??? )   .../EntityManager.php:87
38  0.9929  23690600    Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update\UpdateExtensions->execute( ???, ??? )  .../Update.php:107
39  1.0010  23948800    Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler->execute( ???, ??? )    .../UpdateExtensions.php:49
40  1.0131  23960936    Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->addAttributeUpdate( ???, ???, ??? )  .../CreateHandler.php:167
41  1.0131  23960936    Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->addAttributeUpdate( ???, ???, ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:1155
42  1.0134  23960936    Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->saveAttribute( ???, ??? )  .../Product.php:1764
43  1.0134  23960936    Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->saveAttribute( ???, ??? )  .../Interceptor.php:661
```

Comment: Actually I am wondering where the attribute should be created .. can't find the setup code for it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after migrating data from magento 1.

swatch_image attribute was missing from my migrated attribute set and wasn't available as an used attribute. I just created a new attribute set, added all the unused attributes in a new group.

Went back to the migrated set and swatch_image had magically appeared in the unused attributes - so added it to the image group. Deleted the new attribute set i just made, went back to the product and saved it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done all these steps after upgrading :

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
4. Delete folders except `.htaccess` file from, `<m2_root_directory>/pub/static` and then `<m2_root_directory>/var/view_preprocessed`.
5. Flush Magento cache by typing **`php bin/magento cache:flush`** on command line.

Then recheck it once.